# GitHub REST API Update Branch on a PR

Tags: github-api

GitHub provides this feature of "Update Branch" whenever your PR is not rebased on top of `master`.

Is there a way to trigger this action via the REST API? I was playing around with https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#update-a-pull-request but nothing happened when using `base: 'master'`.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out, I was actually asking the wrong question. Rebasing a PR consists of merging the current HEAD of `master` into your branch, which can be done via

```
octokit.repos.merge({
    owner: pr.head.repo.owner.login,
    repo: pr.head.repo.name,
    base: pr.head.ref,
    head: 'masters_HEAD_sha1',
    commit_message: 'Merging master into this branch'
})
```

Comment: This is not a rebase if you merge the master branch on your PR. You will create a new commit in the PR branch on top of your existing commits whereas rebase will (1) remove the new commits of your branch, (2) update the branch to match the new master base, (3) reapply the new commits.
You should not see in the Github UI a "Merging master into this branch" commit after a rebase.